# Delete DataFrame Columns Based on Row Value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a Pandas `DataFrame`, I'm trying to delete columns that contain any row values greater than or equal to 10<sup>9</sup> and row values less than or equal to 10<sup>-9</sup>.

What would be the best method to perform such an action?

Note: I have NaN types in the `DataFrame`, which I would like to keep, i.e. the code has to work with NaN types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really must keep those values `NaN`, you could first fill them in with a placeholder, then remove the placeholder after filtering.

```
df.fillna('None placeholder', inplace=True)
df = df[(df > 10**(-9)) & (df < 10**9)].dropna(axis=1)
df.replace('None placeholder', np.nan, inplace=True)
```